# Como imprimir un xml desde zeep python?

Tags: python, xml, zeep

tengo ya montada la libreria, segun la documentacion con create_messange() esta me imprime los datos y esta correcto por consola esta bien, solo que quisiera saber si hay manera de crear el archivo xml para guardarlo

```
node = cl.create_message(cl.service, 'LoginYInsertarEvento',
    SystemUser='xxxxx', Password='xxxxx', NroSerie=SSerie,
    Codigo=1, Latitud=SLatitud, Longitud=SLongitud, Altitud=SAltitud,
    Velocidad=SVelocidad, FechaHoraEvento=SFechaIni, FechaHoraRecepcion=SFechaEvento)

outFile = open ('output.xml','w')
outFile.write(node)
outFile.close()

except Exception as e:
    messagebox.showerror(message=e, title="Error")
```

solo lo muestra por pantalla pero no crea nada

Comment: En `outFile.close` te faltaron los paréntesis, debe de quedar `outFile.close()`

Comment: aparte de eso era agregar unas lineas mas

outFile.write(etree.tostring(node).decode("utf-8"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node = cl.create_message(cl.service, 'LoginYInsertarEvento',
    SystemUser='xxxxx', Password='xxxxx', NroSerie=SSerie,
    Codigo=1, Latitud=SLatitud, Longitud=SLongitud, Altitud=SAltitud,
    Velocidad=SVelocidad, FechaHoraEvento=SFechaIni, FechaHoraRecepcion=SFechaEvento)

outFile = open ('output.xml','w')
outFile.write(etree.tostring(node).decode("utf-8"))
outFile.close()

except Exception as e:
    messagebox.showerror(message=e, title="Error")
```

Agregar la libreria lxml con eso bastaria y agregando el etree.tostring para convertirlo a un texto legible podemos imprimirlo